# How to get Random 10 percent data in MYSQL/SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have a data of 50000 Record in my table. My goal is to get 10% random data from the table.

I know i can get top 10% data with `SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT`.

But how to get Random 10% data??

Comment: `TOP` is SQL-Server, not MySQL. Which database are you really using?

Answer (score 4):

Use `select top 10 percent` to get 10% 
and `order by newid()` to get random selection

```
select top 10 percent * from [tablename] order by newid()
```

For `mysql` use

```
select * from [tablename] order by rand() < (select (count(*)/10) from tablename)
```

For a big tables you should use a similar alternative queries.
Please find a good examples [here](https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can get a really good approximation of 10% by using `rand()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where rand() < 0.1;
```